# Add source URL from Feed WordPress (Syndication) plugin to a custom field in post editor

Tags: custom-field, urls, feed

We're using the Feed Wordpress (Syndication) plugin to ingest external feeds resulting in posts published in WordPress.

The plugin pulls the 'source' URL from the feed. We can display the source URL fine against the post on home and post page, but if the feed owner did not include a source URL, it does not exist.

We want to be able to pull the source URL from the feed into a custom field, so that the URL populates the custom field. If the feed has no source URL, then the editor/contributor can access the post editor and add one.

Is it possible to pull the source URL from Feed WordPress (or any other plugin that uses feeds) and populate a custom field with the URL if exists. If not, then the user can add one?

Answer (score 2):

What about the "syndication_permalink"? This is automatically pulled from the feed by FeedWordpress.

Then put something like

```
<?php if (is_syndicated()) : ?>
     <p><a href="<?php the_syndication_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">Source</a></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

in your single post loop.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Syndication->Post & Links.
- On the resulting screen, select the desired feed from the drop-down at top. (Or leave as-is to set a default behavior for all your feeds)
- Scroll down to the "Custom Post Settings" box.
- In the "Key" field, set the name of your custom field(mine is "backlink")
- In the "Value" field set "$(link)"

This will only apply from this point forward, or for any items that are still in the feed XML file, if you have FeedWordPress set up to update existing items.